# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ImagePickerManager.launchImageLibrary')]

Tags: react-native

- I try to develope select images from galary and capture photos from camera .  but i get error and  i don't know how to solve it ,because i am new for react native
- code..................
  import React, {Fragment, Component} from "react";
  import { SafeAreaView,StyleSheet, Text, View , StatusBar , Image , Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
  import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

  ```
     export default class App extends Component {
  ```

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
            fileUri: '',
    };
}

chooseImage = () => {

    let options = {
            title: 'Select Image',
            storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images',
    }
          };
    launchImageLibrary(options, response =>{
            console.log('response = ', response);
    if(response.didCancel) {
        console.log('user cancelled image picker');
    } else {
        console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({
                fileUri: response.assets[0].uri,
              })

    }

          })

} ;
launchCamera = () => {

    let options = {storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images',
    },
    };
    launchCamera(options, response => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);
    if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');

    }else{
        console.log('response',JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({
                fileUri: response.assets[0].uri,
        });
    }
      });
};

renderFileUri() {
    if (this.state.fileUri) {
        return <Image source={{uri: this.state.fileUri}} style={styles.images} />;
    } else {
        return (
                <Image
        source={{
                uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
            }}
        style={styles.images}
                />
        )
    }
}

render() {
    return (
            <Fragment>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.body}>
              <Text  style={styles.textstyle}>Pick Images from Camera & Gallery</Text>
              
              <View style={styles.ImageSelections}>
                  <View>{this.renderFileUri()}</View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.btnParentSection}>
                <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.chooseImage}
    style={styles.btnSection}
            > 
                  <Text>Choose File</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                
              <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.launchCamera}
    style={styles.btnSection}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Directly Launch Camera</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Fragment>
      );
}
```

}

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

        },
        images: {
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginHorizontal: 3,


        },
        body:{
        justifyContent:"center" ,
        backgroundColor:'lightblue',
        flexWrap:"wrap",
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%',



        }
        ,
        textstyle: {
        marginTop:100,
        textAlign:"center",
        fontSize:20,
        paddingBottom: 10,


        },
        ImageSelections:{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection:'row',
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        justifyContent: 'center',

        },
        btnParentSection:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 10,
        },
        btnText:{
        textAlign:'center',
        color: 'gray',
        fontSize:14,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        }
        });
```

- error...........................

  [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ImagePickerManager.launchImageLibrary')]
  at node_modules\react-native-image-picker\src\index.ts:37:4 in Promise$argument_0
  at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
  at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
  at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
  at node_modules\react-native-image-picker\src\index.ts:36:9 in launchImageLibrary
  at App.js:23:10 in chooseImage
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:697:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:634:6 in _receiveSignal
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:528:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackProd
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:342:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:439:41 in executeDispatch
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:463:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2563:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1212:4 in forEachAccumulated
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2588:20 in runEventsInBatch
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2735:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2681:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18204:13 in batchedUpdates$1
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2534:29 in batchedUpdates
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2680:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2800:27 in receiveTouches
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue